# why this instance variable assignment in class method not cause UnboundLocalError in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

In the code below, if using assignment statement on name v in function foo, the interpreter will give unboundlocalerror, because this create a same name variable in function scope, and we try to reference it before locally assigned. But why do the same thing on instance variable in instance method not give any error? what's the difference when Python evaluate `self.v = self.v + 1` and `v = v + 1`?

```
class A:
    v = 1
    def foo(self):
        self.v = self.v + 1
v = 1
def foo():
    v = v + 1

# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'v' referenced before assignment
foo()

a = A()
# print 1
print(a.v)
a.foo()
# print 1 2
print(a.__class__.v, a.v)
```

Comment: Because `self` is defined and `v` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variable resolution is static. At bytecode compilation time, Python recognizes that `foo` has a `v` local variable, so all access to `v` in `foo` goes to the local variable, even if the local variable is unbound.

Instance attribute resolution is dynamic. Whenever a `self.v` access is performed, Python searches through the instance dict and class dicts in the inheritance hierarchy to figure out what `v` is supposed to be. (Assignment always goes to the instance dict unless some other custom behavior has been defined, though.)

Unlike with local variables, the existence of assignments to `self.v` does not by itself affect what attribute access resolves to, and repeated accesses of `self.v` may resolve differently; one access might find nothing in the instance dict and resolve to a `'v'` entry in the class dict, and a later entry might find that a `'v'` entry exists in the instance dict by that point, and resolve to that.